# Identify the incorrect letter in this unusual sequence?

Tags: letter-sequence

Here's a curious sequence of letters:

> H H H E L I P O A
>   L S C S E C S A C

But one of the letters is wrong! Can you figure out which letter is wrong, and what the sequence represents?

(note: two lines used for sequence are simply for the sake of keeping it neat, the newline is not part of the puzzle)

Comment: Looked like the periodic table elements :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> `P` should be `B`.

The sequence represents

> The periodic table overlayed with the Fibonacci sequence.
> H = 1, H = 1, He = 2, Li = 3, `B` = 5, O = 8, Al = 13...

Comment: @mmking That got me for a bit until I realized the line wrapped around.

Comment: Damn it I was so close!

Comment: Well done. And @tfitzger, I didn't explicitly put the newline in to cause that confusion, but I certainly welcomed it - it made it just a little harder to spot the pattern.

Comment: @GlenO I figured as such.